# ASP.NET Core Assigning value to session, giving object reference not set to an instance of an object exception in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core

I set the value in Session in Action Method of Controller then it is working fine. **using ASP.Net Core**

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
   public ActionResult Login()
        {
            HttpContext.Session.SetString("username", "Mohit");
            // this value set to session to this key without error
            return View();
        }
}
```

But I want to use session in another class. To use session I inherite **ControllerBase** but I am not able to set the value in session, getting error object reference not set to an instance of an object

```
public class WeDoShoesApplication : ControllerBase
{
        public bool CreateSession(Login login, string token)
        {
           HttpContext.Session.SetString("name", login.Name);
           //getting error object reference not set to an instance of an object 
        }
}
```

What I am doing wrong here?
Please tell me Whats the solution.

Comment: what is `null`, `HttpContext` or `Session` ?

Comment: I don't get null value.HttpContext.Session.SetString() gives me error of object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: Though `ControllerBase` is the ultimate parent class but is there any specific reason behind not deriving from this from `Controller`?

Comment: @MohitAgrawal then post the stack trace

Comment: Because I am not able to use session in particular class without inheriting ControllerBase or Controller class. Can you tell me Can I use session in another class not in controller class?